# Controller not recognized by HTML after $state.go()

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm fairly new to Angular and very new to using the ui-router, so I could be missing something obvious.

If I launch my results.html page on its own, everything from the Web API is bound correctly through the controller and shows up as expected.

When I start from index.html and click on the button that calls $state.go(), I am navigated to the results.html page .. but none of the data from the controller shows up. The controller & service are still being called though - because I put console.log() statements to verify that the object I want is being returned after $state.go() and it is - the template just isn't registering it.

Here is my code for my ui-router and main controller:

```
// script.js
var app = angular.module('BN', ['ui.router']);

// configure our routes
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)     {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');

$stateProvider

    .state('default',{
        url:'/',
        templateURL:'index.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .state('results', {
        url:'/results',
        controller: 'ResultsController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'Results/Results.html'
    })

    .state('instructor', {
        url:'/api/instructors/:id',
        templateUrl: 'Instructors/Instructor.html'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);
function MainController ($state) {

var vm = this;

vm.Submit=function( ){
    $state.go('results');    
};
}
```

So Results.html renders perfectly fine launched on it's own, but when navigated to - the controller is called but not bound to the html template.

Comment: where is the ResultsController?

Comment: it is in the Results file - but in my index.html file, I include it after this script.js file. @Sajeetharan

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="/Results/ResultsController.js"></script>

Comment: Could you create a plunker for this issue?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hN8xw49bgWJQUiJsyeHj?p=info

@Sajeetharan - my first time using that, let me know if you can see it. I indicated where it was a different folder

Comment: you have not refered the scripts properly, add the cdn links for each script and create a version same as what you get in your local machine and share

Answer (score 0):

You have your index.html file set up properly, but after that you're using ui-router incorrectly.

In your index.html file where you have:

```
<body ui-view>
```

this tells ui-router to load the contents of your templates into the body of your document, so your templates should just be snippets of html to be rendered within your body tag. So you should delete everything from results.html until all that remains is this:

```
<div id="headerBar" >

<div class="form-group" id="headerBar" >
      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputlg" placeholder="Zipcode" />
       <button id="sub" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" ng-click="vm.getInstructors()">Find an Instructor!</button>
</div>
</div>


<table>
                <tr ng-repeat="Instructors in vm.instructors">
                    <td style="padding-top:5px;">
                        <div>
                            <nav class="navbar">
                                <div class="container-fluid">



                                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchString" >
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Filter">Search</button>
                                    </form>



                                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                            </nav>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <div class="col-md-8">


        </div>

<aside class="sidebar" ui-view="map">MAP</aside>
```

A few other things. You have the controller setup in your routes, so you don't need to specify it anywhere in results.html. Also you should not be able to navigate to results.html. Instead you would just navigate to (your domain)/results.

Comment: so this definitely is useful for best practice & cleaning up the solution. However, it's still not fixing the issue. I'm going to the domain/results, and that's when my controller isn't loading into the template still. It is being called - bc the console.log statements I've put in the controller print out. So I'm still not sure if this is an issue with how I'm defining the template or if i need to clarify something in the $state.go() @MikeFeltman

Comment: When you get a chance, clean up the plunker to match what you currently have and I'll take a look.